# Fetching all videos from facebook user news feed page and storing it in database

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fetching all user and user friend's videos from facebook and store it Database](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8688311/fetching-all-user-and-user-friends-videos-from-facebook-and-store-it-database)

I am using rails and I need to fetch all user videos and user friend's videos from facebook and store it in our database(In simple words I have to fetch all videos from user's news feed page in facebook).

Video's like 
                    1)User and user friend's liked videos,
                    2)User and user friend's shared videos,
                    3)User and user friend's tagged videos,
                    4)User and user friend's commented videos,
                    5)User and user friend's uploaded videos, etc

So Is there any easy method to retrive all these videos at same time?? Please reply.. Thanks in Advance